# Loading images into an array in Java

Tags: java, image, awt

I am trying to load some images into an array for an applet and I know there has to be a better way to do this?

```
public class Images extends Applet
{
    Image card[]=new Image[45];
    public void init()
    {
        img[0]= getImage( getDocumentBase(),"pics/1.gif");
        img[1]= getImage( getDocumentBase(),"pics/2.gif");
.....
```

Comment: Best thing to do is probably to have some kind of configuration file which lists the images to be loaded and use `for-loop` to load each one based on the needs of the configuration

Comment: I should have specified that the image names are not all the same - in case that matters

Comment: Do you want to improve performance? Try to use lazy load strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the filenames aren't predictable based on number, you could still have a collection of them. For example:

```
// Common prefix removed for brevity
private static final String[] IMAGE_FILES = {
    "img1.gif", "happy.gif", "sad.gif" /* etc */
};
```

Then:

```
Image[] images = new Image[IMAGE_FILES.length];
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pics/" + IMAGE_FILES[i]);
}
```

(There may well be a nicer way of transforming one array into another using a lambda in Java 8 - I haven't checked.)

It's not clear to me that an `Images` class is a good idea though - it doesn't really sound like something you'd typically create an instance of. I'd also strongly recommend using private fields.